# Business logic software choices

Tags: business-logic

What software do you currently use to implement business logic?

We have an app with very heavy business logic which is implemented in Java with POJO's and EJB's (2.0).

Are there any more recent software languages or tools that are advantageous to use to code business logic?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you mean by "Business Logic", a rules engine such as [Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools/) or [Jess](http://www.jessrules.com/) might be a more efficient way to implement them.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the way to go is to start making the move towards using a rules engine.  I know we have a big push starting to start using a rules engine in one of our applications that is very heavy in decision logic.  Using a rules engine allows you to pull some of that decision logic out of the business logic and allows it to be specified in a more reader friendly format.